# How to implement mavlink nodejs module on Angular Web App

Tags: node.js, angular, browser, mavlink, mission-planner

I have a project in which i need to create an app that is similar to mission planner but in web based form. I am using angular as a frontend development framework. Is there a way to use mavlink module in client side (browser) ? if there is, how can i implement it in angular ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try Browserify, the latest version of node-mavlink has some dependencies on mavlink-mappings which imports the magic_id but it is missing in the latest version so you can use this version of mavlink-mappings "^1.0.8-20220318".For browserify you can follow these steps:

```
npm install -g browserify
```

Now run the usual Browserify command to bundle the JS file from the npm package:

```
browserify node_modules/location_of_the_file -o bundle.js
```

This will produce a bundle.js file outside of node_modules:
This is the file you can bring into the front-end, as one would with a usual JS library.
Then simply add the usual line in the header of my index.html file:

```
<script src="./bundle.js" type="module"></script>
```